# What is the complementary command to 'rx' for xmodem transfer?

Tags: embedded, serial-port, busybox, modem, serial-console

I have an installation of busybox on an embedded linux system that comes with a great little utility called `rx`:

```
rx FILE

Receive a file using the xmodem protocol
```

This is perfect for transferring files from a PC to the embedded system via the serial terminal.  However, I'm also looking to transfer in the opposite direction.  I couldn't find a complementary 'tx' utility.  Does one exist?

Comment: It's been a while since I used that command. I don't recall the exact details anymore. I seem to recall that there were three different protocols each designed for pretty much the same purpose, and each of them had one program to send and one program to receive. If my memory serves me well, you can use `sx` to send and `rx` to receive. (And the other two protocols might have been named y and z rather than x.)

Answer (score 9):

Wow, that has to be the first time this century that I've heard `rx` referred to as a "great little utility"! :-) Yet we can still dust the cobwebs off those old commands.

- **XMODEM**: `rx` for receiving, `sx` for sending.
- **YMODEM**: `rb` for receiving, `sb` for sending.
- **ZMODEM**: `rz` for reveiving, `sz` for sending.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately BusyBox does not have `sx`! This seems surprising to me since it has `rx`. [BusyBox documents](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html)

Comment: I see. Well, I guess that does make some sense since xmodem (and TFTP for that matter) is usually used these days as a last-resort file transfer protocol to load the next stage in a bootloader or update low-level firmware or things like that. Once the system is up and running (bootloader finished its job, firmware running sucessfully, etc...) one usually expects that a "better" file transfer protocol is available.

Comment: Where can we get these tools today?

Answer (score 1):

BusyBox doesn't have the `sx` utility which would be complementary to `rx`, but you can find X-modem in the [`lrzsz` package](https://www.ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html), also available [as a Buildroot package here](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/tree/master/package/lrzsz).